# Get a specific value from non-unique array of values Powershell / Excel VBA

Tags: arrays

I have a csv input file with values similar to below:

```
EmpID LastDay   FeedDate
A123  20150428  2015-04-20
A123  20150428  2015-04-21
A123  20150428  2015-04-21
A444  20150625  2015-06-15
A444  20150625  2015-06-15
A444  20150625  2015-06-16
A444  20150628  2015-06-18
A444  20150628  2015-06-19
F999  20150410  2015-04-02
X666  20150122  2015-01-10
X666  20150122  2015-01-10
X666  20150122  2015-01-10
X666  20150122  2015-01-10
X666  NULL      2015-01-10
X666  20150120  2015-01-10
X666  20150120  2015-01-10
```

Here the the number of entries each EmpID has is not fixed, LastDay may / may not change, FeedDate may / may not be sequential.

Here i need to find the Oldest **FeedDate** with Last **LDIO** 
For e.g. for EmpID A123 it should be :

**A123  20150428 2015-04-20** (since the LastDay didn't change)

For A444 it should be **A444  20150628  2015-06-18**
For X666 it should be **X666  20150120  2015-01-10**

Input is already sorted: EmpID (A to Z) & then on Feed Date (Oldest to Newest)

I'm unable to build a logic where it would loop (probably Do-While) for each unique EmpID since it's not fixed?

Can anyone pls help me understand the logic of how do i achieve this in powershell or Excel VBA?

Comment: still stuck on this logic... ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you would to do the following with your data:

For each unique EmpID:

1. Find the latest LastDay.
2. For this latest LastDay, find the earliest FeedDate.

Here's a script based on this logic. It uses PowerShell's ability to group data based on a property (EmpID) and loop over each group.

**Discrepancy**: The X666 result in your question confuses me as I think 201501**20** should be 201501**22**, based on this logic. Please let me know if that's not the case.

```
# Import your data as CSV object, grouped by EmpID. NULLs are ignored.
$data = Import-Csv ".\input.csv" | Where {$_ -notmatch "NULL"}|  Group -Property EmpID

$results = @()     # Intialise array to store your end results.

foreach ($group in $data){

    # For each EmpID, get the LATEST (Max) LastDay.
    $ld_stats = ($group.Group | Measure -Property "LastDay" -Maximum -Minimum)
    $lastDay  = $ld_stats.Maximum


    # For each EmpID, where the LastDay is the LATEST (Max), get the EARLIEST FeedDate (Min) 
    $fd_stats = ($group.Group | Where {$_.LastDay -eq $lastDay} |`
                 Measure -Property "FeedDate" -Maximum -Minimum)
    $feedDate = $fd_stats.Minimum


    # Put everything together for this particular empID
    $results +=  New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{`
                 "EmpID"=$($group.name);"LastDay"=$lastDay;"FeedDate"=$feedDate}

}

Write $results
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for reply gmsoulman

This is how i resolved it actually

```
$BRID - contains all BRID's in csv file (array)
$LDIO - contains all LDIO's in csv file
$LOAD_DATE - contains all LOAD_DATEin csv file

$PrevBRID = $BRID[0]
$PrevLDIO = $LDIO[0]
$PrevLOAD_DATE = $LOAD_DATE[0]

for($i=0; $i -le $BRID.length-1; $i++)
{
$CompBRID = $BRID[$i]
$CompBRID2 = $BRID[$i+1]

  if($CompBRID -eq $CompBRID2)  
  {
    if($LDIO[$i] -ne $LDIO[$i+1]){
        $PrevBRID = $BRID[$i+1]
        $PrevLDIO = $LDIO[$i+1]
        $PrevLOAD_DATE = $LOAD_DATE[$i+1]
    }
  }
  else{
  #Do Logging
  $writeoutput = "$PrevBRID`t$PrevLDIO`t$PrevLOAD_DATE" | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
  Write-Host "$PrevBRID - $PrevLDIO - $PrevLOAD_DATE"
  $PrevBRID = $BRID[$i+1]
  $PrevLDIO = $LDIO[$i+1]
  $PrevLOAD_DATE = $LOAD_DATE[$i+1]

  #$writeoutput = "$PrevBRID`t$PrevLDIO`t$PrevLOAD_DATE" | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -Append
  }
}
```

Thx again for help...much appreciated :)